# Animate a div on document click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code for animate a div form right to left. (like showing a feedback area). it have 2 divisions 1. Click Here 2. Animate Division.
Now the animation happens only if we click that click here div.
How it will animate(hide) on document click?

```
 $(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () 
    {
        $("#slideouts").animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, 
    function () 
    {
        $("#slideouts").animate({right:'-282px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });


});
```

Comment: Bind a click event to the `document`?

Comment: F.Y.I. [.toggle(function, function, ... ) is removed in jQuery 1.9 release](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it based on document click then you can use:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $("#slideouts").hide().animate({width: "toggle",height: "toggle"}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
});
```

Comment: I made a mistake with your `id`. Now it should work.

Comment: It will hide all div from document.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: After slideout div, on click of outside division- animate slideout div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
$("body").on('click','#sildeouts',function (){
 if($("#slideouts").css('right')=='-282px'){
    $("#slideouts").animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
 }else{
   $("#slideouts").animate({right:'-282px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
 } 
});
});
```